# Writing an alarm clock wanting it to change colors when active instead it only change once with errors

Tags: javascript

Writing an alarm clock wanting it to change colors when active instead it only change once with errors saying :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: ho is not defined
>           at :1:1"

```
 function load() {                                  //global function
      var hVar,mVar;                                   //alarm set variables
      var timer = document.getElementById('timer');    //div with id of timer
      var audio = document.getElementById('audio');    //alarm sound

//my time reference//
      var myDate = new Date();
      Hours   = myDate.getHours();
      Minutes = myDate.getMinutes();
      Seconds = myDate.getSeconds();
      milliSeconds = myDate.getMilliseconds();

// alarms reformating function   
      var Hours = Hours < 10 ? '0'+ Hours : Hours;
      var Minutes = Minutes < 10 ? '0'+ Minutes : Minutes;
      var Seconds = Seconds < 10 ? '0'+ Seconds : Seconds;
      var milliSeconds = milliSeconds < 10 ? '0'+ milliSeconds : milliSeconds;

// string formation output //    
      timer.innerHTML =Hours +':'+ Minutes +':'+ Seconds+':'+milliSeconds;

         var hVar = document.getElementById('inputHours').value;   //alarm hours set
         var mVar = document.getElementById('inputMinutes').value; //alarm minutes set

           var  i=0;                                           //array index variable
           var myColor=['red','blue','green','black','white']; //color array
      function ho(){
           document.body.style.backgroundColor = myColor[i];   //array to dom
           i++;
           while(myColor[i]==myColor.lenght){                  //loop reset
              i=0;
           }
        } 
// if condition for alarm to be active //   
      if (Hours==hVar&&Minutes==mVar){
        audio.play();                               // alarminvokation
        setInterval('ho()','5000');                 //color change invocation
      }
      else {
              audio.pause();
      }
    setInterval('load()','100');
    }
    load();
```

Comment: Do not pass strings to `setInterval`, pass the function's name and a delay in integer format: `setInterval(ho, 5000);`

Comment: Thanx I still have a long way though